# Vector projection to determine elbow in fitted curve

Tags: r, curve-fitting, curve

I have a graph that has been fitted with nonlinear regression.  I would like to calculate the elbow in the fitted curve.  The majority of 2nd differential methods fail to accurately capture this point, and a visual inspection seems to be the only recourse (not useful for automation). The closest thing to an automated "visual" approach would be to use vector projection to calculate the farthest data point from a line that connects the first and last points of the data set (see question mark below).  Can this line, which is normal to the line connecting the first and last point, be calculated using R?

My nonlinear function is:
    result <- lm(y ~ x + I(x^2) + I(x^3) + I(x^4) + I(x^5), data = myData)

[image]

Comment: Yes.  There are a number of ways you could do it.  What have you tried?  What is your nonlinear function?  Are you looking for an "exact" point, or simply the x-value (among those plotted) with the predicted value farthest from the line?  How did you determine the two end points of the curve?

Comment: I have added the nonlinear function to the question. I am "simply" looking for the x-value among those plotted, which is on the predicted line and that is farthest from the straight line made between the first and last points of the predicted line.

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you so much...looks great!! Is it easy to add in the predicted line to the graph? So that we can see both the straight line going across as well as the predicted line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give this a try.  See if it works on your real data.

```
library(MASS)

# fake data
x <- 5:300
y <- (x - 0.03*x^2 + 0.02*x^3 + rnorm(length(x), sd=5000))/1000
myData <- data.frame(x, y)

# fitted curve (I used a simpler example)
result <- lm(y ~ x + I(x^2) + I(x^3), data=myData)
p <- fitted(result)

# line connecting endpoints of fitted curve
i1 <- which.min(x)
i2 <- which.max(x)
slope <- (p[i2] - p[i1]) / (x[i2] - x[i1])
int <- p[i1] - slope*x[i1]

# for every point on the predicted curve (xi, pi), the perpendicular line that goes through that point has
perpslope <- -1/slope
perpint <- p - perpslope*x

# the intersection of the perp line(s) with the connecting line is
xcross <- (int - perpint) / (perpslope - slope)
ycross <- slope*xcross + int

# the distance between the intersection and the point(s) is
dists <- sqrt((x - xcross)^2 + (y - ycross)^2)

# the index of the farthest point
elbowi <- which.max(dists)

# plot the data
eqscplot(x, y)
lines(x[c(i1, i2)], p[c(i1, i2)])
points(x[elbowi], p[elbowi], pch=16, col="red")
lines(x[order(x)], p[order(x)], col="blue")
lines(c(x[elbowi], xcross[elbowi]), c(p[elbowi], ycross[elbowi]), col="red")
```

Comment: I don't think it would not necessarily give the maximum perpendicular from the chord to the prediction curve, but it should be close and we are estimating the curve so it should be "informative".

Comment: Yes agreed. We could argue that doing this visually is never going to be 100% accurate and so similar to this approach.

Comment: @Cybernetic, I added a predicted line, and the perpendicular line to the plot.  I also corrected an error in my calculation of the slope of the perpendicular line, and replotted the data using equal scales, `eqscplot` from package MASS.

Comment: hmmm now the plot looks squished... like this http://s23.postimg.org/cv0dlr957/squshed.png

Comment: Yeah.  I guess this boils down to how you want to define "perpendicular".  I am defining it based on equal scales for x and y (like 1 cm = 833 units in your squished plot).  But if the scales for x and y are different, and you still want a perpendicular looking line, than the equation for that line will be different.  For example, try dividing your `y` by 20 and see what you get.